# Get right path in folder structure

Tags: html, filepath, hugo

I am very new to Hugo and I am using it on my project for first time.

I have a folder structure like this:

[image]

What am I trying to do is set a `link` from `slideTwo.html` file to `tours/circle.thml` file.

**slideTwo.html**

```
<div class="timeline-heading">
  <a href='/tours/circle' class="ctaLinkTours">
    <h3 class="timeline-title">{{ i18n "tour" }}</h3>
  </a>
</div>
```

When user clicks title **TOUR** I want to take him to `tours/circle.thml` and display that particular tour.

My site is static.

I am having trouble to find the path and I am struggling from yesterday so any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: It appears like you're using layouts to store content. Hugo builds the web site using data under content/, and afaik, files under `layouts` do not have a url. They are used as templates to build the site using content/. So, if you have a link `tours/circle.html`, it'll look under `content/tours/circle`, and that content should refer to the layout `circle.hml` to render its contents.

Comment: I would like to point out that this is not a programming question...

Comment: @bserdar thank you! your answer was really helpful. And I did made changes I added `baseof.html` and `list.html` to my folder `tours` in `layouts` and in `content` folder I created `tours` folder that contains all of them. I am getting what I want now. Thank you for that. And can you please right your answer as answer so I can accept it :) it's been helpful to me :)

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg it is not related to go, though similar questions are regularly asked about other tools in SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears like you're using layouts to store content. Hugo builds the web site using data under content/, and afaik, files under layouts do not have a url. They are used as templates to build the site using content/. So, if you have a link tours/circle.html, it'll look under content/tours/circle, and that content should refer to the layout circle.hml to render its contents.